# How to map two virtual adresses on the same physical memory on linux?

Tags: c, linux, memory, low-level

I'm facing a quite tricky problem. I'm trying to get 2 virtual memory areas pointing to the same physical memory. The point is to have different page protection parameters on different memory areas.

On this forum, the user seems to have a solution, but it seems kinda hacky and it's pretty clear that something better can be done performance-wise :
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/19491-map-two-virtual-memory-addres-same-physical-page.html

As I'm facing the same problem, I want to give a shot here to know if somebody has a better idea. Don't be afraid to mention the dirty details behind the hood, this is what this question is about.

Thank by advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Linux kernel 3.17 (released in October 2014) you can use [`memfd_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) system call to create a file descriptor backed by anonymous memory. Then mmap the same region several times, as mentioned in the above answers.

Note that glibc wrapper for the `memfd_create` system call was added in glibc 2.27 (released in February 2018). The [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html) also describes how the descriptor returned can be used to create multiple mappings to the same underlying memory.

Comment: Fantastic! That sounds like the right solution. I had to admit I did lose hope. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to get 2 virtual memory area pointing on the same physical memory.

`mmap` the same region in the same file, twice, or use [System V shared memory](http://fscked.org/writings/SHM/shm-5.html) (which does not require mapping a file in memory).

Comment: This is even worse. If MAP_SHARED is specified, IO will be required and if MAP_PRIVATE is set, copy on write will make the trick inoperant. The solution has the same drawback than the proposed solution in the thread : this share memory accross process in an uncontrolled manner.

Comment: @deadalnix: added a note on System V SHM. There are, AFAIK, no other ways to do this in user space.

Comment: @larsmars > yes System V calls are what is suggested in the link. This is working, but the memory could be hooked pretty easily by another process, which is problematic on security.

Comment: Yep. But there's really no other way. Note that `mmap` implementations can be pretty smart and don't actually write to disk all the time. If you `mmap` a file in `/dev/shm`, there will be no disk I/O at all.

Comment: OK, +1 for all thoses techniques. That's in a way or another always kind of hacky. No real solution but thanks anyway.

Comment: SysV shared memory is secure (though I've always found the key_t a bit clumsy). Any process running with the same euid as yours can map your memory anyway, using ptrace if nothing else.

Comment: SysV is way larger than that. It is not inerrantly unsafe, but you can't do it with any data in memory.

Comment: Is `mmap(..., MAP_SHARED, ...)` guaranteed to point to same **physical memory**, or only that changes will be **visible** to all mappers, which can be implemented through page faults?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose if you dislike Sys V shared memrory you could use [POSIX shared memory objects](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html). They're not very popular but available on Linux and BSDs at least.

Once you get an fd with `shm_open` you could immediately call `shm_unlink`. Then no other process can attach to the same shared memory, and you can `mmap` it multiple times. Still a small race period available though.

Comment: Haha, it's not that I dislike the SysV. What I dislike is to enable memory sharing to achieve something that have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @PerJohansson, I wrote & tested following code, it works well on linux, using mmap with MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED flag, we can map the same physical page allocated by POSIX shm object multiple times and continuously into very large virtual memory.

```cpp
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */


void * alloc_1page_mem(int size) {
    int fd;
    char * ptr_base;
    char * rptr;
    /* Create shared memory object and set its size */
    fd = shm_open("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("error in shm_open");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (ftruncate(fd, 4096) == -1) {
        perror("error in ftruncate");
        return NULL;
    }

    // following trick reserves big enough holes in VM space
    ptr_base = rptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    munmap(rptr, size);

    for(int i=0; i<size; i+=4096) {
        rptr = mmap(rptr, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
        if (rptr == MAP_FAILED) {
            perror("error in mmap");
            return NULL;
        }
        rptr += 4096;
    }
    close(fd);
    shm_unlink("/myregion");
    return ptr_base;
}

void check(int * p, int total_cnt){
    for (int i=0;i<4096/sizeof(int);i++) {
        p[i] = i;
    }

    int fail_cnt = 0;
    for (int k=0; k<total_cnt; k+= 4096/sizeof(int)) {
        for (int i=0;i<4096/sizeof(int);i++) {
            if (p[k+i] != i)
                fail_cnt ++;
        }
    }
    printf("fail_cnt=%d\n", fail_cnt);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char * cmd = argv[1];
    int sum;
    int total_cnt = 32*1024*1024;
    int * p = NULL;
    if (*cmd++ == '1')
        p = alloc_1page_mem(total_cnt*sizeof(int));
    else
        p = malloc(total_cnt*sizeof(int));

    sum = 0;
    while(*cmd) {
        switch(*cmd++) {
            case 'c':
                check(p, total_cnt);
                break;
            case 'w':
                // save only 4bytes per cache line
                for (int k=0;k<total_cnt;k+=64/sizeof(int)){
                    p[k] = sum;
                }
                break;
            case 'r':
                // read only 4bytes per cache line
                for (int k=0;k<total_cnt;k+=64/sizeof(int)) {
                    sum += p[k];
                }
                break;
            case 'p':
                // prevent sum from being optimized
                printf("sum=%d\n", sum);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can observe very low cache miss rate on memory allocated in such method:

```sh
$ sudo perf stat -e mem_load_retired.l3_miss -- ./a.out 0wrrrrr
  # this produces L3 miss linearly increase with number of 'r' charaters
$ sudo perf stat -e mem_load_retired.l3_miss -- ./a.out 1wrrrrr
  # this produces almost constant L3 miss.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are root, you can `mmap("/dev/mem", ...)` but there are caveats in the newer kernels, see [accessing mmaped /dev/mem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891979/accessing-mmaped-dev-mem)