# Accessing mmaped /dev/mem

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mmap

I have simple program that tries to access the physical memory in user space,  where the kernel stores the first struct page. On a 64-bit machine this address is:

> kernel virtual address: ffffea0000000000 physical address: 0000620000000000

I am trying to access this physical address through `mmap` in user space, but the following code crashes the kernel:

```
int *addr;
if ((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC)) < 0 ) {
    printf("Error opening file. \n");
    close(fd);
    return (-1);
}
/* mmap.  address of first struct page for 64 bit architectures 
 * is 0x0000620000000000.
 */
addr = (int *)mmap(0, num*STRUCT_PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE,
            fd, 0x0000620000000000);
printf("addr: %p \n",addr);
printf("addr: %d \n",*addr); /* CRASH. */
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm curious where you got the number 0x0000620000000000 from. It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: i wrote a kernel module to get the address of the first struct page in kernel. This is the address of the 1st struct page on 64bit x86 architecture.

Comment: I believe that 0xffffea0000000000 is correct for the virtual address, but the physical address looks bad. It looks like it came from virt_to_phys, which doesn't handle all addresses.

Comment: Yes, it came from virt_to_phys..

Comment: I can't find any recently updated documentation for `virt_to_phys` but http://dev.man-online.org/man9/virt_to_phys/ says "It is only valid to use this function on addresses directly mapped or allocated via kmalloc." Your guess is as good as mine what they mean by "directly mapped".

Comment: I don't know how to find the physical address, but if your goal is just to read the memory, it would be easy enough to just use the virtual address and `/dev/kmem` or `/proc/kcore`.

Comment: This question is answered here :
Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891979/accessing-mmaped-dev-mem