# mmap64() works in Red Hat 6.6 but not in Red Hat 7.2

Tags: c, linux, x86-64

The function call to mmap64() is as follows:

```
addr = (unsigned char*) mmap64(NULL, regionSize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, FileDesc, (unsigned long long)regionAddr);
```

The arguments typically have values as follows:

```
regionSize = 0x20000;
FileDesc   = 27;
regionAddr = 0x332C0000;
```

Obviously in the code these values are not hard-coded like that, but I just want to show you what the typical values for them will be.

**The problem:**

mmap64() call works perfectly in Red Hat Linux 6.6, kernel version: 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64. It fails in Red Hat Linux 7.2, kernel version: 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64.

No difference in code as far as I'm aware of.

The errno returned is "Invalid argument" or errno #22 (EINVAL). Looking at this reference http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap64, I see 3 possiblilities for the EINVAL error:

1. *We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too large, or not aligned on a page boundary).* -> most likely culprit in my situation.
2. *(since Linux 2.6.12) length was 0.* -> Impossible, I checked length (regionSize) value in debug print, it was 0x20000.
3. *flags contained neither MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED, or contained both of these values.* -> Can't be this as you can see from my function call, only MAP_SHARED flag was given as argument.

So I'm stuck at the moment. Not sure how to debug this. This problem is 100% reproducible. Anyone have tips on what could have changed between the two OS versions to cause this?

Comment: Why not simply use `mmap()` without the suffix if you're building 64-bit executables?  Does that make any difference to your problem?  Are you sure there's nothing already allocated to the region you specify?  What would happen if you let `mmap64()` choose where to place the memory?

Comment: The last argument is called `offset` in the synopsis ([`mmap64()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap64)), and: _`offset` must be a multiple of the page size as returned by `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`._  Is your value a multiple of the page size?  It looks to me like it has too few trailing zeros in the hex (a multiple of 512, not of 4K or larger).

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer (with some comments trimmed as not relevant).*</sup>

Why not simply use `mmap()` without the suffix if you're building 64-bit executables? Does that make any difference to your problem?

However, I think your problem is what you call `regionAddr`.     The last argument to [`mmap64()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap64) is called `offset` in the synopsis, and:

> *offset* must be a multiple of the page size as returned by `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`.

Is your value of `regionAddr` a multiple of the page size? It looks to me like it has too few trailing zeros in the hex (it is a multiple of 512, but not a multiple of 4K or larger).

---

Note that the question originally had a different value on display for `regionAddr` — see also the comments below.

> ```
> regionAddr = 0x858521600;
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> addr = (unsigned char*) mmap64(NULL, regionSize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, FileDesc, (unsigned long long)regionAddr);
> ```

With the revised information (that the value in `regionAddr` is `0x332C0000` or decimal 828521600), it is less than obvious what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) = 4096. The offset is 789315584 (0x2F0C0000) on first try, 853278720 (0x32DC0000) on second try.

It is a multiple of the page size (unless my math is wrong). I'm digging deeper into the offset because it looks like the only thing that could go wrong here.

Comment: That's not what the question says: `regionAddr = 0x858521600;` and `addr = (unsigned char*) mmap64(NULL, regionSize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, FileDesc, (unsigned long long)regionAddr);`.  You may be correct that your real code should be OK (both `0x2F0C0000` and `0x32DC0000` are aligned on 256 KiB boundaries), but we can't help you if you don't show us the real code.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake in my original question. regionAddr should be decimal 858521600 (0x332C0000). About the real code, it's complicated and proprietary. I don't have a good idea of how to organize it into a good question. I'm going to dig deeper at the offset argument, as I believe that is the only argument that could be going wrong here. Is there a way for mmap() to give a more helpful error for debugging other than "Invalid argument"?

Comment: OK; mistakes happen, but it is hard for people to help you reliably when the information in the question is (accidentally) unreliable.  The type of the last argument is, formally, `off_t` — are you sure that's equivalent to `unsigned long long`?  If not, it might account for the trouble.  I also note that the man page has `mmap64()` in the title but plain `mmap()` in the synopsis.  Have you tried replacing `mmap64()` with `mmap()` — and did it make any difference.  I think I'd be surprised if it made a difference, but we need to rule out the improbable too.  Consider an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the help. I think I've found the problem. It's due to the file descriptor argument. We are trying to memory map to /dev/mem which has been protected by the kernel. The exact same problem occured for this poster here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891979/accessing-mmaped-dev-mem. I guess the difference in kernel versions had the different kernel mapping protection implementation. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Interesting. You weren't getting EBADF but the problem was related to the descriptor and what it referenced. Evidently, I should have asked about which file. If you'd mentioned the file, someone else might have spotted the problem sooner. Glad it is solved what's going wrong. Do you have a workaround yet?

Comment: Yup, memory mapping to a location other than /dev/mem solved the issue. Might cause other problems with diagnostic tools still looking for the mapping in /dev/mem but glad we found this issue because it is a bug that would have occurred sooner or later with the (not so) new mapping protection.