# Not able to write in /dev/mem

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

The issue that I am experimenting is not related with `open()` or `mmap()` function, which are executed properly. I have disabled `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` in the kernel so I can read from `/dev/mem` without problems. Actually, I can do the following:

```
const char *path = "/dev/mem"
int fd = open(path, O_RDWR); /* read and write flags*/
p  = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, BASE_ADDR); /* read and write flags*/
```

And the code does not fail. Nonetheless, I am using this code to write in the PCI address space. So, basically the `BASE_ADDR` is `0xc000000`, and the size is 256 MiB (`0x10000000`, all the PCI address space).

Said that, when I try to write on these positions (with a specific offset, BDF format), nothing is written; again the code does not fail, it just does not write anything.

In case my code was wrong, I tried [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/about.html), with the following parameters:

```
[horro@ ~]$ sudo busybox devmem 0xc00b0a8c w 0xffffffff
[horro@ ~]$ sudo busybox devmem 0xc00b0a8c             
0x00000000
```

So, basically it is not writing anything.

Comment: Your code has a typo: `MAP_SHARE` should be `MAP_SHARED`.  But that's clearly not the problem. Please run `sudo strace -o /tmp/devmem.log.txt busybox devmem 0xc00b0a8c w 0xffffffff` and then put the file /tmp/devmem.log.txt somewhere we can see it.  (It will be too long to incorporate into the question, and unfortunately we need to see the entire thing, unedited.)  If you get "strace: command not found" then you will need to install the program first (most Linux distributions put it in a package also called "strace").

Comment: Skimming the code at http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/mem.c gives me the impression that what you are trying to do _is_ supposed to work - but I'm not a kernel hacker and I may have misunderstood it.

Comment: Are you sure that *something is mapped* to the address you're writing to? A PCI device needs to ask the BIOS or the OS for a physical mapping address. If that is not done, the device's memory space will remain isolated from the bus.

Comment: And the code does not fail. :) yes, you simply ignore the return code of open() function

Comment: Also see [How to access kernel space from user space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9662193/608639), [How to access mmaped /dev/mem without crashing the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11891979/608639), [mmap of /dev/mem fails with invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39134990/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM kernel config option. My understanding is that it must be set at compile-time as  CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=n. This is a security reasons.